# Azure backup agent cache - Use temprorary disk

Tags: azure

Can the cache folder for Azure Backup Agent be an azure temporary disk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change the location of cache to a temporary disk (the D drive in Azure VM). Just remember that this disk is not persistent so you can loose data there anytime. To do that, follow those steps to change the cache location:

1- Stop the Backup engine by executing the following command in an elevated command prompt: PS C:> Net stop obengine

2- Do not move the files. Instead, copy the cache space folder to a different drive with sufficient space. The original cache space can be removed after confirming the backups are working with the new cache space

3- Update the following registry entries with the path to the new cache space folder

Registry path : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Backup\Config
Registry Key : ScratchLocation

Value : type your New cache folder location

Registry path : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Backup\Config\CloudBackupProvider

Registry Key : ScratchLocation
Value : type your New cache folder location

4- Re-start the Backup engine by executing the following command in an elevated command prompt: 
PS C:> Net start obengine

Once the backup creation is successfully completed in the new cache location, you can remove the original cache folder.

Comment: Thankyou, but that is the directions to change the cache folder. It doesnt answer the question unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

A long while since this was posted, but I've found the answer - the hard way. If the `D:\` drive is cleared, you will lose the `OnlineBackup.KEK` file in your scratch folder, and backups will fail with an [error 0x86CA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-mars-troubleshoot#encryption-passphrase-not-correctly-configured). But it's not the end of the world. If you update the encryption passphrase (even to the same value), it will start working again. I found instructions for updating the passphrase [here](https://pureinfotech.com/change-backup-encryption-passphrase-azure/).

I've got a script that runs on startup to recreate directories in `D:\` if it's been cleared. I will try saving the `OnlineBackup.KEK` elsewhere, and getting my script to copy it back if needed.